# Shell script not taking arguments from input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have a input file which has user names and subject.

**input**

```
sk7865  /opt/apps/login

sk4888 /opt/apps/info
```

I am writing a shell script to take inputs from the above file and send a mail.

**shell script**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b

    echo echo ""$a""  | mail -s ""$b"" "$a"@example.com

done < input
```

In the above script the actual command I wanted  to use is:-

```
echo "hello world"  | mail -s "a subject" someone@example.com
```

I want it to take arguments a,b at **hello world**, **a subject** to send the email to someone like I used it in the script. But it is not taking the arguments. I think it is something to do with double quotes. Please provide me with proper script.

Comment: please edit, your code is not in a code block, it is very wrong, but I suspect typos.

Comment: To add to @SaintHax' comment: Here's the info on how to [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: also include some lines from the input files

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `do` after your while:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r a b
do
  echo "$a" | mail -s "$b" "$a"@somewhere.com

done < input
```

Remember to always run [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) on your bash scripts before posting here.

Also, you had an `echo echo` in there and double-double-quotes all over the place `""xyz""`.

Comment: He was also missing the # in his #!/bin/bash  And why is he emailing the username to the user?

Comment: @SaintHax: I believe the OP is worried that the user won't know what their user name is, so they're sending it to them just in case :D